# Copy corresponding values from reference to a new list in Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I hope somebody can help me; I've been trying to figure out how to do this all day long.

I have one sheet with a list with corresponding values, e.g. Columns `A`, `B`, `C` make a group of values that have to be together.

In another sheet, I have some values from Column `A`, but not all of them, and want to automatically add the corresponding columns `B` and `C` to it.

So I thought about making a macro that copies the first value from Column A in the incomplete sheet, searches for it in the reference sheet, copies the corresponding values from `B` and `C`, pastes them next to `A` in the incomplete sheet, then copies the next value from `A` and searches for it in the reference table, and so on...

I tried but couldn*t make it work - any ideas? I've wasted way too much time on that problem already! Would do it by hand but have like 40,000 rows of data.

If you know how to do it, help would be MUCH appreciated.

Comment: "I've been trying to figure out how to do that all day long." "I tried but couldnt make it work" Show us what you tried.

Comment: I'm deeply sorry if I offended you, Mr Jean-Francois Corbett. Indeed I have been trying to record a macro that does just what I described in my post in detail. However, due to my obvious stupidity I could not make it work, so I tried to do it with VBA by changing a premade script by somebody else. Alas, if I can't even record a macro, how could I understand VBA? Who did I think I was? So I failed again due to my stupidity. On my further search to solve my problem I found this website, and see there, a friendly user could solve my problem in less characters than your lovely comment. Thank you.

Comment: I'm obviously not the one feeling offended here. You'll find that comments like my first one are fairly common on SO, i.e. inciting OPs to show us what they've tried, instead of just asking for results.

Comment: @JFC. I'm sorry and I apologize for my comment. I can actually quite understand how annoying people are that don't bother to look for answers before they ask questions. Next time when I post here I will include what I already tried :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on these assumptions:

- Complete data is in Sheet1, columns A:C starting at row 2 (Headings in row 1)
- Incomplete data in sheet2, column A starting at row 2 (Headings in row 1)

put this formula in sheet2 cell B2

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A:$C,2,0)
```

put this formula in sheet2 cell C2

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A:$C,3,0)
```

copy these formula down for as many rows as you have data

you can leave the formulas in place, or copy paste values to make permanent

Comment: awesome. and so easy, i'm embarrassed... haha. you saved me tons of time, thank you so so much!!!